# Compare two QMaps

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

What's the best way to compare two `QMaps` and remove the entries not in first map and add the entries of map two to the first one? Let's say I have a map with `{1,2,3}` and a map with `{1,2,4}` and I want to keep in first map `{1,2,4}`. Thanks.

Comment: `Map` has key/value... Which one do you want to compare ?

Comment: I want to compare the key.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example maps this:

```
void removeNonUniqueThenAppend(QMap<QString, QString>& map1, QMap<QString, QString> map2) 
{
   QMap<QString, QString>::iterator iterator = map1.begin();

   while (iterator != map1.end()) {
      if (!map2.contains(iterator.key())) {
         iterator = map1.erase(iterator);
      }
      else {
         map2.remove(iterator.key());
         ++iterator;
      }
   }

   map1.unite(map2);
}
```

Comment: This is good but you need to build a new map. I will try to adapt this, so that the result is stored in the first map. Thanks.

Comment: it is `O(n log n)` whereas it can be done in `O(n)`.

Comment: I don't see a possible `O(n)` here.

Comment: It looks like it causes iterator changes.

Comment: I've amended the above.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. With the values from kh25 a get this result: OneB
One
TwoB
Two
FourB

Comment: I assumed you wanted the duplicates. Are you just looking for the values for the duplicate keys in the first QMap? If so I'll modify again.

Answer (score 1):

You may adapt the following to Qt:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
void my_merge(std::map<K, V>& m1, const std::map<K, V> m2)
{
    auto it1 = m1.begin();
    auto it2 = m2.begin();

    while (it1 != m1.end() && it2 != m2.end()) {
        if (*it1 < *it2) {        // Only in m1
            it1 = m1.erase(it1);
        } else if (*it2 < *it1) { // Only in m2
            m1.insert(it1, *it2); // with hint.
            ++it2;
        } else {                  // In both
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
        }
    }
    m1.erase(it1, m1.end());
    m1.insert(it2, m2.end());
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/sKxoIQ)

[Demo with hint](https://ideone.com/lEOhAL)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly that I was looking for.